# is it possible to decrypt this uuid into a number?

Tags: cryptography, decode, uuid

I have this uuid and I'm interested in finding the information behind it. I have a fair feeling that its a number but I'm not sure where to start to 'decode' it

7da32c8d-1f59-44a2-91b5-ac3a4141fd68

Comment: Atlas_Gondal's answer is quite good.  Generally speaking, a UUID/GUID is used when one wants a globally unique value (sometimes literally---no-one else in the world is using it) but for which there is no official registry to coordinate users.  So a 128-bit value is chosen in a way that is unlikely to be repeated, no matter how many such IDs are generated, even if IDs are chosen continuously until the sun burns out.  RFC 4122 builds them with structure to help guarantee uniqueness, but they are intended to be used as opaque identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official reference for this is [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt), which should probably give you enough information to extract data, although you probably shouldn't rely on it too heavily.

And depending on the kind of UUID it is, it may be generated totally from random bits, or be timestamp-based, or be based on the MAC address. So you may be able to get some of that information, but you can't guarantee you can get anything.

If you are looking for a tool then [OSSP uuid tool](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/) can decode UUIDs. On Debian-based Linux systems you can use `apt-get install uuid` to install it; for other distributions, the package name might be different.

To decode a UUID, use the `-d` (decode) flag:

```
uuid -d AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

For version 1 UUIDs, this gives the MAC address and timestamp -- since that's what's in a v1 uuid.